# What does it mean that "File Stats" are slow on Windows as the reason Ruby is slow?

Tags: windows, ruby

In another question I asked (why is [Rake test so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391387)), part of the response was that:

> The reason is that file stat's in
>   windows are dreadfully slow, and,
>   since Ruby is written on Linux (and
>   optimized for Linux), there hasn't
>   been much work to make it faster.

Can someone explain this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"File stats" mean calls to the operating system to get the status (e.g. permissions) for a file.  Here's a [really interesting post](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/1149) about it;  the summary:

> Today we have three different
>   stat/chmod-models:
>
> ```
> a) UNIX-model           (used in Ruby on Unix)
> b) Ruby-Windows-model   (used in Ruby on Windows)
> c) Windows-model        (used in Windows-applications using
>                          stat/chmod calls)
> ```
>
> I propose that b) should be replaced
>   with c).

Comment: Mind boggling that this was submitted in 2003 and still no work. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Installing_Ruby#Windows_is_slow