# Rails rake: test are slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rake

I've been developing RoR apps for about a month in my Windows Laptop, however everytime that I run the tests it takes forever to finish (10+ minutes).

On a MacBook Pro with similar hardware it runs in a fraction of the time (2 minutes).
Can you guys give me any tips for speeding the whole thing up? or should I consider switching my RoR environment to a Linux/Mac box?

Comment: likely a duplicate of [rake test very slow in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391387/rake-test-very-slow-in-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do most of my ruby development in an Ubuntu VM, just because it is easier to get everything together under linux (I imagine the same applies to OSX). RVM makes my life so much easier.

If your hardware can support it and you don't mind working in a VM, may I suggest you give it a try? VM development has its advantages (namely, taking daily snapshots so you can roll back environment changes) and disadvantages (you lose a bit of speed, but not much these days) but I think it is worth it overall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jamie.
I've an Intel Corei5 Machine with 6GB of RAM on x64 Windows Machine...sure I tried running Ubuntu on a VM and it worked great and speedy, however I was wondering if there's something that I should check on my Windows environment because everything works fine but really slow and that really bothers me.

I just got that unsolved doubt that I want to solve before switching OS.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure about specifics, but I know that ruby development in general is more difficult on windows. Sorry I can't add more than that.

Comment: Ruby development in Windows definitely is way behind...
Switched my main machine to Ubuntu 1 year ago and everything has been great. Thanks for the heads up!