# How can I benchmark why Ruby is suddenly so slow on my machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, rvm, benchmarking

I've been developing Ruby on Rails on my Macbook Pro for quite some time, but recently I'm starting to notice, that everything is just taking forever.

Even simple things like `rake -T` take over 30 seconds to complete.

```
$ time rake -T
real    0m35.113s
user    0m12.997s
sys     0m1.828s
```

When I do the same thing on my VPS, which has much less memory and CPU available, it runs about three times as fast. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 installed via RVM on OS X Lion.

Is there anything that I can check/do to get some instant improvement? I was thinking about upgrading to SDD, but I don't want to make such a decision too early.

Comment: Have you tried seeing how long it takes to do `rake -T` in an empty Rails application? How about seeing how long it takes for ruby to run a script that has no dependencies and just prints "hello world"?

Comment: Check your memory usage.  Long running ruby/rails processes can gobble up a lot of memory, slowing everything down.  Restarting typically helps. Also if you have a large rails environment, it can take a substantial time on the initial load.

Comment: What if you switch to system Ruby, is that slow too? Have you tried imploding RVM and starting from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

It could be some gem's fault, perhaps one that adds a lot of middleware.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461346/slow-rails-stack) might help you.

Also, please try installing 1.9.3, it should perform better at loading.

**Edit**

Just wanted to add that, if all else fails, [the Mac counterpart of] good ole `strace` could be of some help.