# Rails 3 - set_routes_reloader - really slow... why

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

using the railties patch described in this post: [slow rails stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461346/slow-rails-stack), i'm noticing that the step "set_routes_reloader" is regularly taking upwards of 3 seconds.

is this expected? if not, what might i be doing wrong and/or how do i go about figuring out if i'm doing something wrong, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the problem was that we were defining too many routes.  The set_routes_reloader step loads your routes (as you might guess).  We got a lot of mileage by adding the appropriate :except/:only arguments.

Something that may help you is the [traceroute](https://github.com/amatsuda/traceroute/) gem which provides you a list of routes that do not have an associated controller action.  I wrote a one-time script to process our traceroute output and update our routes.rb file.  You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/3286702).