# Rails very slow in Windows 7 due to finisher_hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, performance

I am running Rails 4.2.4 on Win7 x64 and it is very slow for commands like rake test or rails s. After running a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461346/slow-rails-stack/34235814#34235814) that puts the timing into the loop of initializer calls,  I now see that there is a clear bottleneck:

```
                                                .....
                          define_main_app_helper: 0.000 sec
                           add_to_prepare_blocks: 0.000 sec
                           run_prepare_callbacks: 0.016 sec
                                     eager_load!: 0.000 sec
                                   **finisher_hook: 22.514 sec**
                        set_routes_reloader_hook: 0.109 sec
                     set_clear_dependencies_hook: 0.016 sec
                                         for all: 23.950 sec
```

namely finisher_hook @ 22.463 sec!!!

Does anyone have any idea what causes this or could prevent this? I could not find much on the net, except for that it is part of railties.

Comment: Tangentially related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/12220024/525478

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920201/why-is-ruby-so-much-slower-on-windows